# grep: show lines surrounding each match

Tags: search, logging, grep, command-line-interface

How do I `grep` and show the preceding and following 5 lines surrounding each matched line?

Comment: I keep a copy of [Brendan Gregg's perl script](http://www.brendangregg.com/Perl/search) around for this purpose. Works well.

Comment: For a solution that works on Solaris, check out [this link](http://www.unix.com/solaris/33533-grep-display-few-lines-before-after.html).

Comment: `man grep | grep -C 1 context` :)

Comment: `man grep | grep -C 1 "\-C"` ;)

Comment: @StvnW ... I don't know whether to call that [meta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meta#Adjective) (in a more general, rather than SO context), or what to call it. You answered the question by showing how to use the answer to find the answer.

Comment: Perhaps someone [elsewhere in StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/464362/300794) can give us an answer.

Answer (score 5423, accepted):

For **BSD** or **GNU** `grep` you can use `-B num` to set how many lines before the match and `-A num` for the number of lines after the match.

```
grep -B 3 -A 2 foo README.txt
```

If you want the same number of lines before and after you can use `-C num`.

```
grep -C 3 foo README.txt
```

This will show 3 lines before and 3 lines after.

Comment: It is good but unfortunately the Solaris grep does not support that. See that link for solaris: http://www.unix.com/solaris/33533-grep-display-few-lines-before-after.html

Comment: Ok, but what if want to show _all_ lines of output after the match?  grep -A0 and grep -A-1 don't cut it...

Comment: ruffp: I believe there is also GNUgrep

Comment: does not work for me for some reason, although mentioned in my man pages.

Comment: If you are HP-UX env, none of the grep versions will work like in Solaris. Was able to use the Solaris link but replace nawk with awk in that link.

Comment: -n is for line numbers, but for some versions of grep -n# will show # surrounding lines (like -c) with line numbers.  That's a useful shortcut that's my go-to when I need context.

Comment: @g33kz0r, in that case you should ask in a separate question. (Even though someone took the trouble to answer you here, beats me why...)

Comment: Solaris grep does not support this. But gnu grep supports Solaris.

Comment: This works on "Bash on Ubunutu on Windows" as well! The Windows subsystem for Linux uses Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS as of this writing.

Comment: @g33kz0r Do a wc -l on the file, and make that your -A value. Then you know it will display all lines in your file after the match

Comment: zOS grep uses a different flag for leading context: `-P` instead of _-B_.

Comment: Hahaha, `-A` and `-B` it is bad flag, dont it? I first thought it was `above` and `below`, which is the opposite of `after` and `before`!

Comment: Note: You can determine which grep you have using `man grep`. As of 2021, macOS uses BSD grep.«

Comment: @user67416 Use a ridiculously large number for A like `-A99999999`

Comment: Is it possible to specify the before/after lengths in words or characters? I'm processing Youtube vtt transcripts where everything is on one line.

Answer (score 660):

`-A` and `-B` will work, as will `-C n` (for `n` lines of context), or just `-n` (for `n` lines of context... as long as n is 1 to 9).

Comment: I tried the `-n` format and found out it only works till `9`. For `15` it returns 5 lines

Comment: @DeepakMahakale This is probably related to how command-line arguments / options are typically parsed by POSIX programs. The option specifier is a single character (such as `-A`, `-B` or `-C`). Usually, the option specifier is followed by a value (`-o a.out` to specify output file in GCC), but it can also function as a simple switch / flag (`-g` to enable debugging info in GCC). However spaces between options are optional, so for options without a value, it is possible to merge them (`-ABC`), which means that `-15` is interpreted `-1 -5` (two separate options) and the `-5` overrides the `-1`.

Comment: -5 is quicker than both -A 5 -B 5. Those are not meant to be used together. It is cleaner to other readers of the script if you choose -A or -B or -C over -9.

Comment: The `-n` option currently works for more than 9 lines on (GNU grep) 3.1.

Answer (score 42):

```
grep astring myfile -A 5 -B 5
```

That will grep "myfile" for "astring", and show 5 lines before and after each match

Comment: "grep astring myfile -C 5 "  will do the same

Comment: Wow that's great!
A = after, 
B = before, 
C = context

Answer (score 23):

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

If you care about the performance, use [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which has similar syntax to `grep`, e.g.

```
rg -C5 "pattern" .
```

> `-C`, `--context NUM` - Show NUM lines before and after each match.

There are also parameters such as `-A`/`--after-context` and `-B`/`--before-context`.

The tool is built on top of [Rust's regex engine](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex) which makes it very [efficient](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/) on the large data.

Answer (score 22):

I normally use

```
grep searchstring file -C n # n for number of lines of context up and down
```

Many of the tools like grep also have really great man files too. I find myself referring to [grep's man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) a lot because there is so much you can do with it.

```
man grep
```

Many GNU tools also have an [info page](http://web.archive.org/web/20090427121543/http://www.gnu.org:80/software/grep/doc/grep_toc.html) that may have more useful information in addition to the man page.

```
info grep
```

Answer (score 21):

**Let's understand using an example.**
We can use grep with options:

```
-A 5  # this will give you 5 lines after searched string.
-B 5  # this will give you 5 lines before searched string.
-C 5  # this will give you 5 lines before & after searched string
```

**Example.**
File.txt contains 6 lines and following are the operations.

```bash
[abc@xyz]~/% cat file.txt # print all file data
this is first line
this is 2nd line
this is 3rd line
this is 4th line
this is 5th line
this is 6th line

[abc@xyz]~% grep "3rd" file.txt # we are searching for keyword '3rd' in the file
this is 3rd line

[abc@xyz]~% grep -A 2 "3rd" file.txt # print 2 lines after finding the searched string
this is 3rd line
this is 4th line
this is 5th line

[abc@xyz]~% grep -B 2 "3rd" file.txt # Print 2 lines before the search string.
this is first line
this is 2nd line
this is 3rd line

[abc@xyz]~% grep -C 2 "3rd" file.txt # print 2 line before and 2 line after the searched string 
this is first line
this is 2nd line
this is 3rd line
this is 4th line
this is 5th line
```

**Trick to remember options:**

1. `-A`   → A means "**A**fter"
2. `-B`   → B means "**B**efore"
3. `-C`   → C means "in between"

Answer (score 19):

Use grep

```
$ grep --help | grep -i context
Context control:
  -B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
  -A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
  -C, --context=NUM         print NUM lines of output context
  -NUM                      same as --context=NUM
```

Comment: Did you not read the accepted answer? You are just repeating what has already been said on a question almost 10 years old...

Comment: Oh I'm sorry Yokai. But I don't read anything about grepping the help section of grep to retrieve the answer.

Comment: @Yokai Besides what Chiel ten Brinke said, the accepted answer does not mention the long options

Answer (score 19):

If you search code often, [AG the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is much more efficient (ie faster) than grep.

You show context lines by using the `-C` option.

Eg:

```
ag -C 3 "foo" myFile

line 1
line 2
line 3
line that has "foo"
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

Comment: On what system (incl. distribution name and version) did you try it? Was it installed by default? If not, what are some installation instructions? It is not installed by default on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 15):

Search for "17655" in `/some/file.txt` showing 10 lines context before and after (using `Awk`), output preceded with line number followed by a colon. Use this on Solaris when `grep` does not support the `-[ACB]` options.

```sh
awk '

/17655/ {
        for (i = (b + 1) % 10; i != b; i = (i + 1) % 10) {
                print before[i]
        }
        print (NR ":" ($0))
        a = 10
}

a-- > 0 {
        print (NR ":" ($0))
}

{
        before[b] = (NR ":" ($0))
        b = (b + 1) % 10
}' /some/file.txt;
```

Answer (score 12):

I do it the compact way:

```
grep -5 string file
```

That is the equivalent of:

```
grep -A 5 -B 5 string file
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is the [@Ygor solution](https://www.unix.com/302098992-post2.html?s=4309a3b1b120fabe0d81368129bc8921) in `awk`

```
awk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=3 a=3 s="pattern" myfile
```

<sup>Note: Replace `a` and `b` variables with number of lines before and after.</sup>

It's especially useful for system which doesn't support grep's `-A`, `-B` and `-C` parameters.

Comment: Very nice.  Yes, it is more complex-looking, but it is actually cross-platform.  Tested on AIX and HP-UX.

Answer (score 7):

Grep has an option called `Context Line Control`, you can use the `--context` in that, simply,

```
| grep -C 5
```

or

```
| grep -5
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 5):

```
$ grep thestring thefile -5
```

`-5` gets you `5` lines above and below the match 'thestring' is equivalent to `-C 5` or `-A 5 -B 5`.