# Unix Bash shell command to grep some text if another grep matches

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I have an XML file in unix directory. I would like to search for some character if that is present, then grep the text located 3 lines before this matched line,.

**Here is My File: (abc.xml)**

```
<task Col="5" Object="BCD">
<checkpoint TcpOn="0"/>
<after ActFlg="0"/>
</task>
<task Col="6" Object="ABCD">
<checkpoint TcpOn="0"/>
<after ActFlg="1"/>
</task>
<task Col="7" Object="ABCDE">
<checkpoint TcpOn="0"/>
<after ActFlg="1"/>
</task>
```

**Unix Code:**

```
grep -i 'actflg="1"' abc.xml
```

**Current Answer:** This is returning the line where it is located.

```
<after ActFlg="1"/>
<after ActFlg="1"/>
```

**What i Want is :** (i want to do a further grep to display **output as follows** if actflg="1" is found...)

```
<task Col="6" Object="ABCD">
<task Col="7" Object="ABCDE">
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for a XML parser.  See `xmllint`.

Comment: @devnull : No, it can any file.. this scenario is for xml file.. I have other files as well..

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep show 5 lines above grepped line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281343/grep-show-5-lines-above-grepped-line)

Comment: @devnull : This is not duplicate.. This is not working, if the same actflg="1" repeats multiple time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep -B XX`, which print XX lines before matching lines. Then you use `head -1` to just print the first one:

```
$ grep -B2 -i 'actflg="1"' file
<task Col="6" Object="ABCD">
<checkpoint TcpOn="0"/>
<after ActFlg="1"/>

$ grep -B2 -i 'actflg="1"' file | head -1
<task Col="6" Object="ABCD">
```

---

In case there are multiple matches, you can do:

```
$ awk '/ActFlg="1"/ {print preprev} {preprev=prev; prev=$0}' file
<task Col="6" Object="ABCD">
<task Col="7" Object="ABCDE">
```

#### Explanation

- `'/ActFlg="1"/ {print preprev}` matches lines containing `ActFlg="1"` and does print `preprev`, a stored line.
- `{preprev=prev; prev=$0}` this keeps storing the two previous lines. The 2 before is stored in `preprev` and the previous in `prev`. So whenever we are in a new line, this gets updated.

Comment: This is not showing , if the same actflg="1" repeats multiple time

Comment: Well I replied based on your sample input. If you change the sample, don't come and downvote...

Comment: I did not do that !! Please remember that i am here to ask for help ! anyone's answer is well appreciated even if it is wrong because they help me !!

Comment: OK I thought it was your downvote. It is a bit tricky because the way to do it will be `awk` but having the "ignore case" comparison it is more difficult. Will try to find a moment to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Thanks.. even if it is case sensitive its okay.. because its predefined structure file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47032/discussion-between-logan-and-fedorqui)

Comment: @logan updated with some information, hope it is clear.

Comment: error when using `-B` it in Solaris machine : `grep: illegal option -- B
grep: illegal option -- 2
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .`

Comment: it have raised it here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149908/awk-command-to-print-last-5-rows-if-matched