# awk command to print last 5 rows if matched

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, solaris

I have an xml file. I need to print five lines before the matched text.

There may be multiple matches. I am using following awk command which is returning only one row.

```
awk '/<\/ABC>/' file.xml
```

**returns**

```
<ABC>Some Text1</ABC>
<ABC>Some Text2</ABC>
<ABC>Some Text3</ABC>
```

**Expected:**

```
... previous 4 lines ...
<ABC>Some Text1</ABC>
... previous 4 lines ...
<ABC>Some Text2</ABC>
... previous 4 lines ...
<ABC>Some Text3</ABC>
```

---

Cannot use `grep -B` [as per in Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629549/unix-bash-shell-command-to-grep-some-text-if-another-grep-matches?lq=1#comment33609952_21629615):

> grep: illegal option -- B grep: illegal option -- 2 Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
awk '(NR>1){{a[NR]=$0;if($0~/<\/ABC>/){for(i=NR-4;i<=NR;i++){print a[i]}}}}' input.txt
```

Comment: Its good. But it is not printing the matched line. prints only the previous lines

Comment: Yes it will. Linux uses GNU version of awk. It has many additional feature which default POSIX version of solaris awk does not have.

Comment: Super. How should i perform another awk on the previous lines alone ?

Comment: just change `i<=NR` to `i<NR` in the for loop `for(i=NR-4;i<=NR;i++)`

Answer (score 4):

For Solaris:

```
nawk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=2 a=4 s="string" file1
```

"b" --> the number of lines to print before string "s".

"a" --> the number of lines to print after string "s".

Linux:

```
grep -B4 '<ABC>' file.xml
```

Comment: @logan No, but `awk` & `grep -B` will work on Linux.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide awk command solution ? becuase, i may execute the commands in a shell file in any unix box

Comment: Just replace nawk with awk. Do you awk on your box?

Comment: if i replace it says error in solaris box `awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
-bash-3.00$
`

Comment: Sorry, not able to test.