# How do I fetch lines before/after the grep result in bash?

Tags: grep

I want a way to search in a given text. For that, I use `grep`:

```
grep -i "my_regex"
```

That works. But given the data like this:

```
This is the test data
This is the error data as follows
. . . 
. . . .
. . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . .
Error data ends
```

Once I found the word `error` (using `grep -i error data`), I wish to find the 10 lines that follow the word `error`. So my output should be:

```
. . . 
. . . .
. . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . .
Error data ends
```

Are there any way to do it?

Comment: From your description it seems you want the 10 lines proceeding the word `error`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep a file, but show several surrounding lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines)

Answer (score 377, accepted):

You can use the `-B` and `-A` to print lines before and after the match.

```
grep -i -B 10 'error' data
```

Will print the 10 lines before the match, including the matching line itself.

Comment: Thanks this is working. But when I tried to store this execution in the variable like this `test=$(grep -i -B 10 'error' data)`, and print it using `echo $test`, I get the straight long lines as output.

Comment: Thanks I figured out I need to do like this `echo "$test"` rather than `echo $test`

Comment: `-C 10` will print out 10 lines before AND after in one fell swoop!

Comment: is there a way to do this using a specific before point? say the length i have to grab prior is variable?

Comment: grep -i -m 1 -A 100 -B 150  'wordd' file.txt

Answer (score 68):

This prints 10 lines of trailing context after matching lines

```
grep -i "my_regex" -A 10
```

If you need to print 10 lines of leading context before matching lines,

```
grep -i "my_regex" -B 10
```

And if you need to print 10 lines of leading and trailing output context.

```
grep -i "my_regex" -C 10
```

**Example**

```
user@box:~$ cat out 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5 my_regex
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
user@box:~$
```

**Normal grep**

```
user@box:~$ grep my_regex out 
line 5 my_regex
user@box:~$
```

**Grep exact matching lines and 2 lines after**

```
user@box:~$ grep -A 2 my_regex out   
line 5 my_regex
line 6
line 7
user@box:~$
```

**Grep exact matching lines and 2 lines before**

```
user@box:~$ grep -B 2 my_regex out  
line 3
line 4
line 5 my_regex
user@box:~$
```

**Grep exact matching lines and 2 lines before and after**

```
user@box:~$ grep -C 2 my_regex out  
line 3
line 4
line 5 my_regex
line 6
line 7
user@box:~$
```

**Reference: manpage grep**

```
-A num
--after-context=num

    Print num lines of trailing context after matching lines.
-B num
--before-context=num

    Print num lines of leading context before matching lines.
-C num
-num
--context=num

    Print num lines of leading and trailing output context.
```

Comment: Nice, ive had to look this up a few times now, maybe I can remember it as   
-A(FTER)    
-B(EFORE)    
-C(ONTEXT)

Comment: I am trying the same logic but getting below error -
$ grep -A 20 'Exception in thread \"main\"' overnight.231122.log

Comment: But I am getting this error -

grep: illegal option -- A
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern [file...]
[deuxvi1i:/pkg/vdc05/dirsrv05/overnight_log][dirsrv05]$

Answer (score 11):

The way to do this is near the top of the man page

```
grep -i -A 10 'error data'
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
grep -i -A 10 "my_regex"
```

-A 10 means, print ten lines after match to "my_regex"

Answer (score 1):

This may help you with finding an exact string before and after matching strings in a command.

You'll have to use two grep commands, using the pipe "|" operator. The command in the first pipe uses grep to print out all the text that appears a specified number of lines before the matching string, and an additional pipe operator makes grep to output the exact text *after the matching string*, ignoring the exact text that appears before or after the targeted string, further narrowing down the output.

Here's the template combination command that outputs only a specific string that's located specified number of lines before the specified string in the first "grep -B" pipe (replace the text between the {} symbols with your own):

> {command-with-desired-output} | grep -B {number-of-lines-between-text-after-and-wanted-text} '{matching-string-after-wanted-value}' | grep -oP '(?<={exact-string-before-wanted-value}).*')

The "grep -B {number}" parameter prints all the contents for a desired number of lines that appear before the matching string, including the line matched, while cutting off everything that appears after the desired number of lines is reached - use "grep -A" if the desired value appears *after* the matching string.

The second grep command. "grep -oP", finds the matching string and prints everything after it until it reaches the end of the current line, while excluding the matching string.

Example command I used to find the Sink Input of a gmediarender sink:

> pactl list sink-inputs | grep -B 20 'application.name = "gmediarender"' | grep -oP '(?<=Sink Input #).*')

An easy way to find how many lines before the matched string there are is to paste the output of just the grep -B command into gedit (you can use CTRL+SHIFT+C to copy highlighted text from the terminal, or right-click and copy), and read the amount of lines there - it will appear in the lower right corner of gedit's window as "Ln".

> sudo apt-get install -y gedit

Comment: This advice is too big and contains a lot of useless information, please rewrite it in a convenient form.

Comment: @ Sergei Voronezhskii I've trimmed down my advice significantly hope it's satisfactory now.