# How to append a line after a search result?

Tags: bash, grep

So I grep for something in some file:

```
grep "import" test.txt | tail -1
```

In test.txt there is

```
import-one
import-two
import-three

some other stuff in the file
```

This will return the last search result:

```
import-three
```

Now how do I add some text -after-- import-three but before "some other stuff in the file". Basically I want to append a line but not at the end of a file but after a search result.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines

Comment: After each block of matches, or the first block of matching lines, or the last? The first two are easier.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want some text after each search result, which would mean after every matching line. So try

```
grep "import" test.txt | sed '/$/ a\Line to be added'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with `sed`

```
sed '/import-three/ a\
> Line to be added' t
```

#### Test:

```
$ sed '/import-three/ a\
> Line to be added' t
import-one
import-two
import-three
Line to be added

some other stuff in the file
```

Comment: As *import-three* may change, what about making it more general? Something like `text=$(grep "import" test.txt | tail -1)` and then `sed "/$text/ a\..."`

Comment: True .. `Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man how to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.` :)

Answer (score 1):

One way assuming that you cannot distingish between different "import" sentences. It reverses the file with `tac`, then find the first match (import-three) with `sed`, insert a line just before it (`i\`) and reverse again the file.

The `:a ; n ; ba` is a loop to avoid processing again the `/import/` match.

The command is written throught several lines because the `sed` insert command is very special with the syntax:

```
$ tac infile | sed '/import/ { i\
"some text"
:a
n
ba }
' | tac -
```

It yields:

```
import-one
import-two
import-three
"some text"

some other stuff in the file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ed`](http://man.cx/ed):

```
ed test.txt <<END
$
?^import
a
inserted text
.
w
q
END
```

Meaning: go to the end of the file, search backwards for the first line beginning with import, add the new lines below (insertion ends with a "." line), save and quit