# grep - return surrounding lines for each hit

Tags: grep

I'm using grep in a search that returns significant false-positivies, and it's probably easier for me to identify the good results by inspection, than to write the much more complicated grep expression.

To do that, I need to see more than 1 line for each result.

Can I (How do i) instruct grep to return 1-2 lines above and below each match?

Comment: For this, and other such queries, 'man grep' is your friend.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your grep expression? What are you attempting to search for?

Comment: for some reason "man grep" didn't work properly on my machine, but a better choice of google search terms, did. Feel free to close if appropriate

Comment: @blueberryfields well, you could delete this question. And you could also give an answer providing the solution to your problem

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines?rq=1, with more info there

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have *GNU* `grep`, then:

`grep -A 2 -B 2` or `grep -C 2`
`-A` stands for after
`-B` stands for before
`-C` stands for context (both before and after)

Source and more options: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: Great! Thanks Andy for adding `-C`