# How do you grep a file and get the next 5 lines

Tags: shell, grep

How do I `grep` a file for `19:55` and get the Line 1,2,3,4,5?

```
2013/10/08 19:55:27.471
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5

2013/10/08 19:55:29.566
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Comment: Your title looks brilliant. You know - no, I don't grep a file and get it's 5 lines :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep a file, but show several surrounding lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines)

Answer (score 267, accepted):

You want:

```
grep -A 5 '19:55' file
```

From `man grep`:

```
Context Line Control

-A NUM, --after-context=NUM

Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  
Places a line containing a gup separator (described under --group-separator) 
between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

-B NUM, --before-context=NUM

Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  
Places a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) 
between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

-C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM

Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing a group separator
(described under --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.  
With the -o or --only-matching option,  this  has  no effect and a warning
is given.

--group-separator=SEP

Use SEP as a group separator. By default SEP is double hyphen (--).

--no-group-separator

Use empty string as a group separator.
```

Comment: It would be great if there was a way to not limit the output to a certain amount of lines but print *all* lines after the matched one.

Answer (score 4):

Some `awk` version.

```
awk '/19:55/{c=5} c-->0'
awk '/19:55/{c=5} c && c--'
```

When pattern found, set `c=5`
If `c` is true, print and decrease number of `c`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sed solution:

```
sed '/19:55/{
N
N
N
N
N
s/\n/ /g
}' file.txt
```