# how to ouput the current line and next line if the next line match special condition

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file. It contains some line like this:-

```
I don't want to see this line 1 and next line.
exception: 14
I want to see this line 1 and next line.
exception: 16
I don't want to see this line 2 and next line.
exception: 13
I want to see this line 2 and next line.
exception: 19
```

I want the output like this:-

```
I want to see this line 1 and next line.
exception: 16
I want to see this line 2 and next line.
exception 19
```

I tried to use awk to solve it. But cannot get the right result.
My awk script:

```
$ cat test.awk  
awk '
  {if ( $2 > 14 )  print prev $0; next}
' test.txt
```

Result:

```
$ ./test.awk
I don't want to see this line 1 and next line.
I want to see this line 1 and next line.
exception: 16
I don't want to see this line 2 and next line.
I want to see this line 2 and next line.
exception: 19
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this, then you are missing something small, you never define `prev`:

```
awk '/^exception:/ && ($NF > 14) {print prev; print $0} {prev = $0}' file
```

You also should say that your line should start with `exception:` otherwise, you might have problems when you have a line like

```
exception: 2
Some 15 years ago I had an exception
exception: 1
```

This would print something wrong.

Otherwise, use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) (See [How do you grep a file and get the next 5 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274127/how-do-you-grep-a-file-and-get-the-next-5-lines))