# git nearest regex matched tags to commit

Tags: git, tags, git-log

I have a shortlog in my git history like this:

```
1234213 commit A tag: positive_1  
1234324 commit B  
1111111 commit C  
4543533 commit D tag: negative_1  
1234234 commit E tag: positive_2  
4534543 commit F  
4543533 commit G tag: positive_3
```

And I would like to have a git command which shows me two or more positive regex matched tags that are nearby to specified commit. For 1111111 for example, output should be like:

```
1234213 commit A tag: positive_1  
1111111 commit C  
1234234 commit E tag: positive_2  
4543533 commit G tag: positive_3
```

I have a necessity to know which version of product contains specified fix/feature. The command would make it easier to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want. But this is my attempt

```
> cat text.txt
1234213 commit A tag: positive_1
1234324 commit B
1111111 commit C
4543533 commit D tag: negative_1
1234234 commit E tag: positive_2
4534543 commit F
4543533 commit G tag: positive_3
> cat text.txt | grep -A 5 -B 5 1111111 | grep -E "positive|1111111"
1234213 commit A tag: positive_1
1111111 commit C
1234234 commit E tag: positive_2
4543533 commit G tag: positive_3
```

I grep on the commit hash and [grab 5 leading and 5 trailing lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274127/how-do-you-grep-a-file-and-get-the-next-5-lines). After that we match on the tag itself and/or include the original commit hash.