# How to grep for lines above and below a certain pattern

Tags: grep

I would like to search for a certain pattern (say Bar line) but also print lines above and below (i.e 1 line) the pattern or 2 lines above and below the pattern.

```
Foo  line
Bar line
Baz line

....

Foo1 line
Bar line
Baz1 line

....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep a file, but show several surrounding lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `grep` with the parameters `-A` and `-B` to indicate the number a of lines `A`fter and `B`efore you want to print around your pattern:

```
grep -A1 -B1 yourpattern file
```

- `An` stands for `n` lines "after" the match.
- `Bm` stands for `m` lines "before" the match.

If both numbers are the same, just use `-C`:

```
grep -C1 yourpattern file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat file
Foo  line
Bar line
Baz line
hello
bye
hello
Foo1 line
Bar line
Baz1 line
```

Let's `grep`:

```
$ grep -A1 -B1 Bar file
Foo  line
Bar line
Baz line
--
Foo1 line
Bar line
Baz1 line
```

To get rid of the group separator, you can use `--no-group-separator`:

```
$ grep --no-group-separator -A1 -B1 Bar file
Foo  line
Bar line
Baz line
Foo1 line
Bar line
Baz1 line
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
          Places   a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)  between
          contiguous groups of matches.  With the  -o  or  --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print  NUM  lines  of  leading  context  before  matching lines.
          Places  a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)   between
          contiguous  groups  of  matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line  containing  a
          group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.  With
          the -o or --only-matching option,  this  has  no  effect  and  a
          warning is given.
```

Comment: complete answer. +1 for the --no-group-separator

Answer (score 3):

`grep`is the tool for you, but it can be done with `awk`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} $0~s {f=NR} END {for (i=f-B;i<=f+A;i++) print a[i]}' B=1 A=2 s="Bar" file
```

NB this will also find one hit.

or with `grep`

```
grep -A2 -B1 "Bar" file
```

Comment: @Jonte Could you explain your command? Also is it possible to do this for multiple hits rather than just one?

Comment: @user1692342 awk store all lines in an array named `a`, then it start printing out lines if it match the `B` before and `A` after hits.  Yes awk can handle multiple hits, but may become rather complex.