# How to grep a line with unknown distance before a line

Tags: regex, bash

I know that I can grep lines above and below a certain pattern, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313494/how-to-grep-for-lines-above-and-below-a-certain-pattern).
Now I have a problem, I want to grep a line before a certain pattern, but I don't know how far it is, such as:

```
Time 00:00:01
kkk
lll
aaa
...
Time 00:00:03
kkk
kkk
kkk
lll
lll
aaa
aaa
...
Time 00:00:04
kkk
lll
...
```

My target pattern is aaa, and the other pattern is "Time xx:xx:xx" and I want the output like this

```
Time 00:00:01
aaa
Time 00:00:03
aaa
aaa
```

or

```
Time 00:00:01
aaa
Time 00:00:03
aaa
Time 00:00:03
aaa
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the significance of `aaa`?

Comment: So you want to match those `aaa` occurring within some `Time 00:XX` block and print both values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your exact output

```
awk '/^Time/{a=$0}/aaa/{print a"\n"$0}' file

Time 00:00:01
aaa
Time 00:00:03
aaa
Time 00:00:03
aaa
```

or

```
awk '/^Time/{a=$0;x=0}/aaa/{print (x++?"":a"\n") $0}' file

Time 00:00:01
aaa
Time 00:00:03
aaa
aaa
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you give me what I want^^

Comment: It is impossible to address to you!

Answer (score 3):

You Can use the following:

```
(Time[^\n]*|aaa)
```

https://regex101.com/r/cY8jN7/2

The same thing for use in `grep`:

```
Time[^\n]*|aaa
```

EDIT: This regex will replace everything except for what you need, so the output is correct:

```
Time[^\n]*\n((?:(?!Time|aaa)[^\n]*(\n|$))*(?=Time|$))|(?<=\n)(?!Time|aaa)[^\n]+\n
```

https://regex101.com/r/xP1hT0/1

Comment: Won't this also print times don't have aaa ?

Comment: How would you use the new one ? `grep -P 'Time[^\n]*\n((?:(?!Time|aaa)[^\n]*(\n|$))*(?=Time|$))|(?<=\n)(?!Time|aaa)[^\n]+\n'` returns nothing.

Comment: Nvm, grep can only match on single lines, so multiline regexs will not work, although the regex is valid for something that does :).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it in Perl:

```
perl -ane '$t=$_ if /Time/; print $t,$_ if /aaa/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's real simple with grep:

```
$ grep -E 'Time |aaa' file
```

**Matcher Selection**

-E, --extended-regexp
           Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see
           below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)