# How to grep a unknown distance line above a pattern

Tags: regex, perl, awk

Sorry to edit the question again. I found that I didn't ask my question clearly before.
I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097346/how-to-grep-a-line-with-unknown-distance-before-a-line) yesterday but I found another problem today /.\
Here is my file:

```
Time 00:00:01
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa: 88
...
Time 00:00:03
jjj
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa: 89
ooo
bbb
aaa
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa: 90
...
Time 00:00:04
kkk
lll
...
```

Here is the output I want:

```
Time 00:00:01
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa: 88
Time 00:00:03
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa: 89
Time 00:00:03
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa: 90
```

Last time I was looking for one line and the other line above it. This time I am looking for a pattern with multiple lines:

```
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa: /any thing here/
```

and a line

```
Time /any thing here/
```

From the question I asked yesterday, I tried

```
awk '/Time/{a=$0}/kkk\nlll\nccc\naaa/{print a"\n"$0}' file
```

and

```
perl -ane '$t=$_ if /Time/; print $t,$_ if /kkk\nlll\nccc\naaa/' test2
```

and

```
pcregrep.exe -M 'kkk.*(\n|.)lll.*(\n|.)ccc.*(\n|.)*aaa' test2
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)
but they are not working or the output is not what I want.

I found a thread like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350856/can-awk-patterns-match-multiple-lines) which is talking about state machine but it is complex since I have several lines to match.

Any suggestion that can solve this problem easily?

Comment: You are trying to output the set of lines that starts with `kkk` and ends with `aaa` and the `Time` line that immediately proceeds them?

Comment: More than that, `kkk`, `lll`, `ccc` and `aaa` must match at the same time and same order. and the `Time` line proceeds them immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer was written for the *first* version of this question.)

```
$ awk -v RS="Time" -v p="\nkkk\nlll\nccc\naaa" '$0~p {print "Time",$1,p;}' file
Time 00:00:01 
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa
Time 00:00:03 
kkk
lll
ccc
aaa
```

(This may require GNU awk.)

Comment: I am sorry, I missed a requirement and I edited my post, the requirement is that if there are more than one pattern appear under line `Time`, then I have to print out all of them. How to add this case to the command? Also what is mean by $0~p ?

Comment: The test `$0~p` returns true if the current record, `$0`, contains text that matches the regular expression `p` where `p` is defined earlier on the command line to be the lines that you are looking for.

Comment: It may not need `gnu awk`, it needs `gnu awk` due to multiple characters in  `RS`