# grep command to print follow-up lines after a match

Tags: solaris

how to use "**grep**" command to find a match and to print followup of 10 lines from the match. this i need to get some error statements from log files. (else need to download use match for log time and then copy the content). Instead of downloading bulk size files i need to run a command to get those number of lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep a file, but show several surrounding lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines). You can't because Solaris has an antique grep, but there are a few alternatives listed here.

Answer (score 8):

A default install of Solaris 10 or 11 will have the `/usr/sfw/bin`  file tree.  Gnu grep - `/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep`  is there.  ggrep supports `/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -A 10 [pattern] [file]`  which does what you want.

Solaris 9 and older may not have it.  Or your system may not have been a default install.  Check.

Comment: Above solution holds good for file.How do I use "ggrep" on command output?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you have a file `/etc/passwd` and want to filter user "**chetan**"

Please try below command:

```
cat /etc/passwd | /usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -A 2 'chetan'
```

It will print the line with letter "**chetan**" and the next two lines as well.

**-- Tested in Solaris 10 --**

Comment: Tested on SunOS 5.10 and running the following: ggrep -A 2 'Script ended' *.xml