# extract all lines from a file to a seperate file with new lines as delimiter

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a file where data packets comes at high speed.
I want to extract all packets from main file to another file after finding ip.

Main file "Main.cap" -

```
Device:A
Host:B
IP:0.0.0.0
Time:123654

Device:B
Host:C
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423


Device:C
Host:D
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:129423


Device:E
Host:F
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423


Device:G
Host:H
IP:1.2.5.6
Time:12543
```

Now from this file if i want to extract all packets from IP `1.1.1.1` i.e. all 4 fields and all 3 packets then what should be done?

In short we have to grep this ip `1.1.1.1` and then find 2 new lines,one above this ip and one after ip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep a file, but show several surrounding lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines)

Comment: @fedorqui- Thanks for the link, can you please confirm, will it give all the packets from the file? say if i do `grep 1.1.1.1 -B 2 -A 1 Main.cap > output.txt` then all packets will come?

Comment: Test it yourself. Note it would be handy to use `grep -F "1.1.1.1"`, so that the `.` are understood as plain dot, not any character. All together, `grep -B 2 -A 1 -F "1.1.1.1" Main.cap`.

Comment: @fedorqui- there is one edition which is size of all packets is not same so new line delimiter is must. any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

awk is really good at this sort of thing.  As long as there is a blank line between records, you can do:

```
awk '/IP:1\.1\.1\.1/' ORS='\n\n' RS= input-file
```

Setting `RS` to the empty string makes awk treat blank lines as the record separator, so you just have to match the IP to print the entire record.  (Use `\.` to match a literal `.`)  It's not strictly necessary to assign ORS, but it makes the output prettier.

Comment: In what way is it not working?  Are your blank lines truly blank, or do they contain any whitespace?  Are you using exactly the command above (cut-n-paste) or are you writing `RS=input-file`?