# How to grep second results from text file in Bash?

Tags: bash, grep

I have text file with this content:

4

```
:
      ID: 5
      table: 4
      numplan: no_change
      accs-cat: no_change
      cld-rule: $
      cld-type: no_change
      cld-numplan: no_change
      clg-rule: '----------+79975532211'
--
    17:
      ID: 19
      table: 7
      numplan: no_change
      accs-cat: no_change
      cld-rule: $
      cld-type: no_change
      cld-numplan: no_change
      clg-rule: '----------+79975532211'
--
    18:
      ID: 20
      table: 3
      numplan: no_change
      accs-cat: no_change
      cld-rule: $
      cld-type: no_change
      cld-numplan: no_change
      clg-rule: '----------+79975532211'
--
    19:
      ID: 21
      table: 5
      numplan: no_change
      accs-cat: no_change
      cld-rule: $
      cld-type: no_change
      cld-numplan: no_change
      clg-rule: '----------+79975532211'
```

How I can grep results like this:

```
4:
      ID: 5
      table: 4
      numplan: no_change
      accs-cat: no_change
      cld-rule: $
      cld-type: no_change
      cld-numplan: no_change
      clg-rule: '----------+79975532211'
```

Then I grep this result :

```
17:
      ID: 19
      table: 7
      numplan: no_change
      accs-cat: no_change
      cld-rule: $
      cld-type: no_change
      cld-numplan: no_change
      clg-rule: '----------+79975532211'
```

Then I have this result:

```
18:
      ID: 20
      table: 3
      numplan: no_change
      accs-cat: no_change
      cld-rule: $
      cld-type: no_change
      cld-numplan: no_change
      clg-rule: '----------+79975532211'
```

Then I have this result:

```
19:
      ID: 21
      table: 5
      numplan: no_change
      accs-cat: no_change
      cld-rule: $
      cld-type: no_change
      cld-numplan: no_change
      clg-rule: '----------+79975532211'
```

I need grep this results in one Bash script. How to do it?

I need get first result, and then next results in my text file

Comment: What do you need to do with these sets of results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep a file, but show several surrounding lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you record `4`..

```
grep -A8 '[[:space:]]*4:' file
```

and so on.. The command takes in to account, that the record will be `8` lines long, `-A8` will output the matching line and the `8` lines following it.

You can create a little loop to execute the command for every record of interest and redirect the output of the loop to a text.file:

```
for i in 4 17 18 19 ; do
    grep -E -A8 "[[:space:]]*$i:" input.txt
done > output.txt
```

---

Alternatively you could use `awk` using a record separator `RS="\n *--\n"`:

```
awk -F$'\n' '$1 ~ /\y(4|17|18|19):/' RS="\n *--\n" input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! It's work!

I use this:

```
for i in 4 17 18 19 ; do
    grep -E -A8 "[[:space:]]*$i:" input.txt
done > output.txt
```