# Display 5 lines after the match of a specific word in ubuntu with terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, line, display

how to Show 5 lines after the match of a specific word like "Charlie" in ubuntu with terminal

Comment: Pls add example string you want to match a word from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep a file, but show several surrounding lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines)

Comment: Display 5 lines after the match of the word “Bombay”. @syadav

Comment: @syadav i am waiting for your answer

Comment: Welcome to SO community. Please refer [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask question in a better way.

Comment: Display 5 lines after the match of the word “charlie”. please help on this @syadav

Answer (score 0):

Below is the input file **test.txt**

```
$cat test.txt
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
```

Run this command to get 5 lines.

```
grep Charlie test1|head -5
```

output:-

```
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
Charlie:Harry:Ram
```

Comment: not like that                    
gege
gege
Charlie
a
b
c
d
e
f    this is the input  and the out put comes like         a
b
c
d
e
f   inshort after charlie 5 line comes @syadav

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is what you're looking for, but your question is not particularly clear.  Please post more information, such as a section of the file you're searching in if this doesn't answer your question!

`grep -A 5 "Charlie" myfile.txt`