# What is the replacement/equivalent of grep -B / -A option in Unix?

Tags: bash, grep, posix

As Unix does not offer `-A` or `-B` options with grep, I am looking for the way to achieve the same result in Unix.
The purpose is to print all the lines not starting with a specific pattern and the preceding line.

`grep -B1 -v '^This' Filename`

This will print all the lines not starting with the string `'This'` and the preceding line. Unfortunately my script needs to be run on Unix.
Any workaround will be great.

Comment: What do you mean by _Unix_? Do you mean you can only assume [`grep` features defined by _POSIX_](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)?

Comment: Could you specify your flavour of *Unix*? [This answer+comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9083/668501) suggest that GNU utils are posix compliant, but others unix implementations are not Posix compliant, but differes from vendor to vendor

Comment: @Soren, what does GNU grep's conformance with POSIX have to do with it?  Its `-A` and `-B` options are not part of POSIX, which seems to be the point of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern/{if(NR>1){print previous};print}{previous=$0}'
```

Explanation:

```
# If the pattern is found
/pattern/ {
    # Print the previous line. The previous line is only set if the current
    # line is not the first line.
    if (NR>1) {
        print previous
    }
    # Print the current line
    print
}
# This block will get executed on every line
{
    # Backup the current line for the case that the next line matches
    previous=$0
}
```

Comment: @ hek2mgl : Your suggestion seems to be useful. Thanks. But the bracketing in the command may need a review. Could you please check and correct as needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. changed it

Comment: Excellent! This works. I understand 'NR>1' part.Would you help me understand the meaning of - {print last};print}{last=$0} .

Comment: Pretty comprehensive! I was thinking awk only filters out the specific lines matching with the pattern specified in the beginning. But it does not seem so. "# This block will get executed on every line" - Assuming this to be each and every line of the file, I have my confusion resolved now. Thanks much!  Not sure, If  should ask/post in a different thread - But I am sure you can help me with this. What would be the command to find all the lines not starting with a specific pattern and then appending it to the previous line.