# Why is grep returning non-matched lines

Tags: linux, grep

Why is grep returning non-matched lines? You can see grep highlights the match. How can I get the desired behavior? This is in Ubuntu.

> $ service --status-all | grep 'friendly'
>   [ ? ]  apport
>   [ ? ]  console-setup
>   [ ? ]  cryptdisks
>   [ ? ]  cryptdisks-early
>   [ ? ]  dns-clean
>   [ + ]  **friendly**-recovery
>   [ ? ]  irqbalance
>   [ ? ]  killprocs

Nothing funny in the alias.

```
$ alias
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

Comment: Cannot seem to replicate.

Comment: at command line type: "which grep" to see which grep you are using.
I just tried your command (using the same alias) and only get output containing the expected match. I am running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's not grep. It is `stderr` being sent to the console.

```
$ service --status-all > test.txt
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 ...
```

vs.

```
$ service --status-all 2> test.txt
<no output>
```

So a possible solution is to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` then grep:

> $ service --status-all 2>&1 | grep 'friendly'
>    [ + ]  **friendly**-recovery

Answer (score 0):

You can control the amount of context displayed before and after the match using the `-C` flag, i.e `service --status-all | grep -C 0 'friendly'` will only display the exact lines that matched without any context.

For more information you can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083/2791719