# Python: How to grep full stacktrace log with keyword

Tags: python

How to grep full trace log based on a keyword like 'Outofmemory' in Python as I tried `readline()` to grep the line instead of entire log trace. Share the snippet, please.

Comment: If you know that the stack is about 10 lines, use the "after" parameter: `grep Outofmemory -A 10 your_trace.log` https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083/2375207

Comment: Thr number of lines is differs in each error.pls help to grep the full trace through python.