# How to make grep display surrounding lines?

Tags: unix, grep

For example, I run a command like:

```
grep -r "MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION" . --include "CMakeLists.txt"
```

and get:

```
/qtdoc/examples/demos/photosurface/CMakeLists.txt:           MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION "Resources")
./qtwebengine/src/core/api/CMakeLists.txt:        PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources/qtwebengine_locales
./qtwebengine/src/core/api/CMakeLists.txt:        PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources
```

How to improve this command and make it display not only the line of code containing `MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION` but a code snipped containing 5 lines before and 5 lines after `MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION`?

Comment: Which version of `grep` do you use?

Comment: Have you looked at `man grep`? You should see `-B` and `-A`, to include content before and after a match, if you have a GNU version.

Comment: I've removed the bash tag, as this isn't a bash question: bash has no control over what options your copy of grep has, and it'll be the same options no matter if you're running grep from bash, ash, zsh, Python with `shell=False`, an `exec`-family call from C, etc; it's your OS vendor, in deciding which version of `grep` to include, that makes the relevant decision.

Comment: Anyhow -- I'd argue (1) that this question would be more on-topic at [unix.se], as it's not specific to software development; and (2) that it isn't answerable at all, either here or there, unless you specify your OS or otherwise which version of grep you have.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy grep version: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: Although not within the current scope of SO, this was [asked and answered in 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-show-lines-surrounding-each-match) as automatically shown in the Related section (at least for me)