# Why is a topic locked as off-topic

Tags: stack-overflow

Why is this topic locked as off-topic?

[grep: show lines surrounding each match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-show-lines-surrounding-each-match)

This seems totally arbitrary. Please explain why and by whom are topics like this locked.